# If / Else logic involving text i Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-office-2010

I want to perform the following logic in a Microsoft Excel 2010 worksheet:

```
In cell E3: if C3 = Off or off then VALUE=0, else Value=C3*D3
```

Where cell C3 will contain either a number or the word 'off' allowing for capitalization.  And E3 always resolves to a numerical value.  If capitalization cannot be allowed for, requiring all lower case is the preferred form.

I've tried:

```
=IF(C3="off", 0, C3*D3)
```

but E3 always returns #VALUE! no matter the value of C3.  I had cell type set to Currency for E3, and General for all other cells.

What do I need to enter into E3, and how must the cells be formatted to get the desired result?

Comment: C3*D3 will give you an error if either of those two are text values, what are the possible values for C3 and D3? Are those values from formulas or something else?

Comment: C3 will contain either: off, Off, or a float value with two digit precision between 0.25 and 16, inclusively.  C3 data in C3 is either entered directly or imported from a web-form.  D3 will always be a float value with two digit precision between 8 and 100, inclusively.  E3 needs to always return a numberic value, FLOAT or INT doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IF(LOWER(C3)="off",0,C3*D3)` should do the job regardless of actual `off` case. However, It's unclear what is in `D3` - perhaps this cell causes error, since this formula works fine for me.

Comment: If you do a straight comparison like `=C3="off"` that's never case-sensitive so LOWER function isn't required.....

Comment: @barryhoudini thanks for the hint, didn't know about that!

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should actually work. You can also do a hack:

```
=IFERROR(C3*D3,0)
```

In case C3 contains "Off" - or any other text - `C3*D3` will result in an error - and `IFERROR` will ocnvert this error to the desired `0`.

Comment: This formula worked, however Peter's suggestion still returns an error if an unusable value gets into C3 which is more desireable for my current use. 1^ for you.